# Permission error when attaching GDB to PID of running process

Tags: permissions, process, debugging, gdb, ptrace

I have such a toy C++ program

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int n{};
    std::cin >> n; // waits for input
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

which pauses upon executing the commented line, waiting for the user input and giving me all the time I want for attaching a debugger to it.

I run this program in a terminal, and in another terminal I enter

```bash
gdb -p $(pidof that-executable)
```

with the intention of attaching the debugger to the executable that the source code above was compiled to.

However, the attempt results in the following error:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Attaching to process 1086551
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions (one temporary and one permanent) are outlined in [this answer to a similar if not identical question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/41656/523488).

The section *Running a program with temporary capabilities* in [this ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Capabilities#Running_a_program_with_temporary_capabilities) gives an alternative solution.

I've tested the temporary solution at the first link and the solution at the second link. They both work.

Since I'm in doubt about what is the right way to do it, I've also [asked on ArchLinux' forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2051596#p2051596).

Answer (score 0):

`gdb` may be blocked on security grounds given what `gdb` allows an attacker to do (steal or change private keys from peer processes in a user environment, etc). Therefore modern OS typically restrict what `gdb` has access to.

The best method would probably be to run the program under `gdb` instead of attaching over to a process; this typically is allowed by default, though may be tricky to setup.

Otherwise, there may be a configuration value (e.g. `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` on [Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt), or the `kern.global_ptrace` sysctl on OpenBSD) that adjusts what `gdb` is allowed to access. Or, run `gdb` as `root`, but that may introduce other problems. Or, a container on Linux may first need to be granted the `SYS_PTRACE` capability. A process that has called `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE...)` may be difficult to trace.

On Linux, selinux or other such security frameworks could also cause the operation to fail. Try setting them to permissive.